# When I clicked and Select Spinner item then Cursor will go automatically in Blank edit-text?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, spinner

For example: Spinner containing 3 four items like Cash,Check.i have also declare 3 edit text like checkno,chekdd,amount paid. When I clicked Cash Item then it Will link to amount paid edittext automatically.

```
Spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
            View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        if(spinnerText2.equalsIgnoreCase("CASH"))
        {
            amountedittxt.setText(spinnerText2);
            amountedittxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you expand on what you mean? Right now your question is meaningless. Edit the description to make sense and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DylanGattey plz help :)

Comment: Do you want amountedittxt to get focus when you select CASH?

Comment: @PurpleDroid sir. yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set focus on your edittext you can call `requestFocus` on it.

```
if(spinnerText2.equalsIgnoreCase("CASH"))
{
    amountedittxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    amountedittxt.requestFocus();
    amountedittxt.setText(spinnerText2);
}
```

Make sure you have added `android:focusable="true"` in xml for edittext like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

Comment: Happy coding :) Mark answer as correct so it gets removed from unanswered questions @17Coder :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one also

String amountedittxt=textExm.getText().toString();

```
               textExm.setFocusable(true);
                textExm.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                textExm.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: This one exact code match i found :)                                                  amountedittxt.getText().clear();
amountedittxt.setEnabled(false);